# Is $\phi^4$ theory an attractive or repulsive force?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, interactions

- Does the well known $\phi^4$ theory, with Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}
  \partial_\mu \phi\partial^\mu \phi-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4,$$
  yield an attractive or repulsive force for the $\phi$ particles? (Here we use the $(+,-,-,-)$ sign convention.)
- And does there exist also a potential in the Born Approximation (as we have for the Yukawa interaction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda>0$, the force is repulsive. If it $\lambda<0$, the force is attractive, but the system is unstable to vacuum decay.

To be more specific  $\lambda \phi^4$ interaction is the relativistic version of the Schrodinger delta-function potential.

Comment: Could you expand on both statements, how are they justified? It would make the answer way more helpful

Comment: $\lambda \phi^4$ is a scalar version of self-action, not a delta-function potential (which is an external potential).

Comment: @ Vladimir Kalitvianski It is a point-contact particle-particle interaction which,correseponds to a  $\frac 12 \sum_{ij}\delta^d(r_i-r_j)$ potential.

Comment: Mike, could you elaborate more on your last statement, and offer a proof or demonstration of this delta interaction (from the field quartic term)?  This is interesting.

Comment: A "local" QFT is a point-contact particle-particle interaction, but no external potential is involved, so no analogy with delta-function potential exists. On the contrary, there is a strong self action of a "free" particle on itself. Thus, we do not know how exact $\phi$-particle looks like, if exists.

Comment: @Cham: If you write the usual non-relatvistic many-body delta interaction in second-quantized bosonic form you get a $(\phi^\dagger \phi)^2$ interaction, You can also do the particle-trajectory expansion for the relativistic lattice version.   I think there is an old paper by Coleman which gives a particle interaction interpretation, but I could not find it with a quick look.

Comment: @ohneVal One way to justify these statements is to compare the non-relativistic limit of the relativistic scattering amplitude, with a non-relativistic QM calculation of the scattering amplitude with a delta function potential. Physically the "delta function" makes sense since $\phi^4$ is a purely local interaction, so all 4 $\phi$ particles involved in the interaction need to be at the same point. Jackiw comments on the connection in a work on self-adjoint extensions: https://inspirehep.net/literature/313843

Comment: As for $\lambda=0$, Sec. I.4 of A. Zee's _Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell_ shows two point "charges" interacting via $\phi$ have an attractive Yukawa potential.

Comment: @J.G. *Exchanging* a bose field is always attractive, so a $\bar\psi \psi \phi$ interaction with $\psi$ a fermion and $\phi$ a boson gives an attractive interaction. There is no particle exchange in $\lambda\phi^4$.  If you try to use Hubbard-Stratanovich to  write it as $g\phi^2 \chi$, $g$ real,  and integrate out the $\chi$ to get a $\phi^4$ you end up with a negative $\lambda$.

Comment: @mikestone Pardon my terminology. But just as positive masses attract via a spin-$2$ graviton (we think!) and positive electric charfes repel via a spin-$1$ photon, you can do something similar with spin-$0$ and get another sign change, as the parity hinges on counting spacetime indices.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. I should have said *scalar* bose field  is always attractive. If we could get a repulsive interaction we could do  some nice  lattice computations in the Hubbard model